# alternate way to store large dynamic objects, instead of session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have a web application developed in .net 2.0
I am storing large business objects in session, which change frequently.

Some times I observe server error. Is this causing the error?

Is there any alternative way to store these objects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "large business objects" and why do you need to persist them on a user-by-user basis?

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? If you can post the exception we might be able to answer that question.

Comment: Use the database because its supposed to store large objects and even more if they freuquently change.

Comment: The objects contain many variables which need to be updated from the web service(every 5 seconds). comparing the variables stored in session and those retrieved from web service, I need to perform some operations. Then i need to update the session objects.

Comment: Error I am facing is  " object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: What data that a per-user needs to be updated every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a database on a user by user basis.

EDIT

Cache the results if you are wanting to read every 5 seconds.

Might not be the solution though.

Comment: Since I poll for the data every 5 seconds, doesn't it reduce the performance?

Comment: Cache the results from the database so that you are reading the data from the cache rather than the database. Just an idea, might not suit your needs though

Comment: Without knowing what the data is, he shouldn't need to cache it, his queries should be ~1s.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing business objects in session you would be better of with an architecture that allows you to store the data in a database, and cache data for an appropriate period of time.

Your current architecture using session will ultimately have scaling issues unless you store the session data in a database, so, you might as well get the data from the database in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you've provided, it doesn't seem like the issue is performance related.

On the "Object reference not set error".   It seems to me that there is a thread synchronization issue.  The session object is retrieved and used while/before you are trying to set the session object(s) to the value from your service call.   You could add thread synchronization(ReaderWriterLock?) to see if that minimizes the error.